# Add a read more link to product list

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a view with a grid displaying rendered entity of product list for my product display index. Is it possible to add a read more link to the product list display with a link to the product. I have tried to create this in several different ways, by creating a link in the content type fields, however that would require manual completion. I appreciate that if I was using fields in views I could add the link there. I'm hoping there is a solution to adding to the product list. I have also looked at adding it manually to node.tpl.php, but I am unsure of where to define the variable instead of $teaser. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using Commerce Kickstart, so Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I added all of the required fields from product list to teaser, then modified the css accordingly.